# flash scope issues in grails when cookies are disabled

Tags: grails

In my application I want to have some dynamic content available to search engine bots which have cookies disabled. But I am stuck because I need to pass redirect URL via flash scope to redirect to different action and controller. When I use chain 
 instead of redirect then I am able to get flash scope data but I have some use cases in which I cannot use chain and have to use redirect this is also because chain (uri: '/') does not work correctly as this will redirect to index action of current controller and not to the controller that is defined for root '/'.  The issue is that flash scope loses everything when cookies are disabled and doing redirect instead of chain. Is this a bug in grails or know limitation in grails?

When cookies are disabled I still see URL being rewritten with ;jessionid=some_value but according to documentation by default 
url would not be rewritten with jessionid. When cookies are enabled then url is not rewritten as expected. Is this a bug in grails or expected behavior? How do I disable URL rewriting in grails when cookies disabled?

I also understand that the implication of disabling cookies and URL rewriting is that each request would result in new session object creation.

Comment: Thanks I looked at that plugin but it does not solve my problem that I described in my posted question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the solution you are looking for, but have you tried [Marc Palmer's One-Time Data](http://www.grails.org/plugin/one-time-data) plugin?